# Deleting from an aliased join construct

Tags: t-sql, join, alias, sql-delete

I want to delete from a join construct, that I have to supply an alias ("mapped") for, since I also have to use an EXISTS clause on the join in the end. So the whole thing looks something like that:

```
DELETE a
FROM (TableA a INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT * FROM TableX x INNER JOIN TableY y ON x.id = y.id) map
      ON a.key = map.key) mapped
WHERE EXISTS
      (SELECT * 
       FROM  LookUp l 
       WHERE l.key1 = mapped.TableAKey 
       AND   l.key2 = mapped.TableXKey
       AND   l.key3 = mapped.TableYKey)
```

The problem seems to be with the parenthesis, because I get an error:

> ```
> Incorrect syntax near 'mapped'.
> ```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just rewrite it so you're deleting from an explicit table and handle all of your conditions in the where clause something like this.

```
DELETE TableA
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT * 
        FROM 
            TableX x 
            INNER JOIN TableY y ON x.id = y.id
        WHERE
            x.key = TableA.key and
            EXISTS (
                SELECT * 
                FROM  LookUp l 
                WHERE l.key1 = TableA.TableAKey 
                AND   l.key2 = x.TableXKey
                AND   l.key3 = y.TableYKey
            )
    )
```

Also note it may be helpful to replace `DELETE TableA` with `SELECT * FROM TableA` while you're working on the where clause to see exactly what records are going to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the DELETE statement needs to reference an alias used in your FROM clause. Since your alias is 'mapped', try changing the DELETE as follows:

```
DELETE mapped
FROM (TableA a INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT * FROM TableX x INNER JOIN TableY y ON x.id = y.id) map
      ON a.key = map.key) mapped
WHERE EXISTS
      (SELECT * 
       FROM  LookUp l 
       WHERE l.key1 = mapped.TableAKey 
       AND   l.key2 = mapped.TableXKey
       AND   l.key3 = mapped.TableYKey)
```

Comment: thanks for the hint, but that don´t work either. Same error message.

Comment: besides i´m not sure, if this way still ensures, that i delete from the particular table i wnat to delete from?!